# React JS add key value pair to existing Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, javascript-objects

I have array of objects where i need to an key value

useState :

```
const [row, setRow] = useState([{ nameofthework: "", schedulerefNo: "", unitprice: "", qty: "", uom: "", gst: "", total: "" }]);
```

The form input change function

```
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...row];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setRow(list);
    console.log(row);  // Prints out the each row object into and array of objects
};

const handleQty = (e) => {
    const scheduleNumberForQuantity = e.target.value;
    projectScheduleNumber?.filter((v) => {
        if(v["Schedule No"] === scheduleNumberForQuantity ) {
            setScheduleQuantity(v["LOA Qty"]); // return only integer example 1000
        }
    })
}
```

How to add handleQty value to row state ?

Comment: You're mutating the state. Don't mutate state in React

Comment: can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need declare the state like a function instead of array of objects key value. It will allow setRow to be managed as function in any moment inside of the function component.

```
const [row, setRow] = useState<any>();
```

With `<any>` allows save anything. So you could apply a strong type like:

```
const [row, setRow] = useState<()=>void>();
```

or in you case

```
const [row, setRow] = useState<(e: any)=>void>();
```

I hope it is useful for you.